# How to get variable from another compressed file with closure compiler

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Hello I want to integrate Closure compiler by Google to compress my files with ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS mode but I have 2 compressed files and I need to share variables between both.

I read this documentation https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3

**Issue**

I got this error :

> ReferenceError: getValue is not defined

so I tried to replace getValue by window['getValue'] but it does not working.

**Basic code**

First JS FILE :

```
var nb0 = 0;
var nb1 = 1;
var nb2 = 2;
var nb3 = 3;

function getValue( nb ) {
    return nb;
}

window['nb0']           = nb0;
window['nb1']           = nb1;
window['nb2']           = nb2;
window['nb3']           = nb3;
window['getValue']      = getValue;
```

Second JS FILE :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 

    var val = getValue;

    document.querySelector( ".button" ).addEventListener( "click", upButton );

    function upButton() {

        val++;
        document.querySelector( ".show" ).innerText = val;

    }

} );
```

Comment: `var val = window.getValue`

Comment: I also tried that

Comment: I got undefined

Comment: It'll also depend on the order in which you include the files. The first file needs to be included before the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is stated, if briefly, under the subheading
*[Solution for Calling out from Compiled Code to External Code: Externs](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#mixed)* in the document you've linked.

I imagine your confusion comes from the words "third-party" and "external". In the context of this document, you can assume "third-party" and "external" refers to both code written by others, **and** any code that comes from any files compiled separately (by you or others).

The solutions then are either to prepend `/** @export */` to the vars you wish not to be renamed, or to define an [externs](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#externs) file for your sources.

## Alternate 1

If you wish to continue using `window` in this manner (it might be ugly, imho there are times when this is appropriate), you should change

```
var val = getValue;
```

to

```
var val = window['getValue'];
```

For example:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 

    var val = window['getValue'];

    document.querySelector( ".button" ).addEventListener( "click", upButton );

    function upButton() {

        val++;
        document.querySelector( ".show" ).innerText = val;

    }

} );
```

compiles to

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var a = window.getValue;
  document.querySelector(".button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    a++;
    document.querySelector(".show").innerText = a;
  });
});
```

## Alternate 2

Use [ES6 modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import). Closure Compiler [supports these with the `module_resolution` flag](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/JS-Modules).

General reading: [Encapsulating Code With Modules](https://github.com/nzakas/understandinges6/blob/master/manuscript/13-Modules.md)
:

## Alternate 3

Use the [Google Closure Library's modules](https://github.com/google/closure-library/wiki/goog.module:-an-ES6-module-like-alternative-to-goog.provide) (goog.module, goog.require, and (deprecated) goog.provide).

Comment: Thank you for your thank you for your constructive response. I got this for Alternate 1 :  

`window.getValue=function(){return 1};document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){var a=window.getValue;document.querySelector(".button").addEventListener("click",function(){a++;document.querySelector(".show").innerText=a})});`

In my index page i got error NaN

Comment: I'm working on a project that was created ten years ago so I don't use ES6.

Comment: I decided combine this file to only one with command line in the documentation  :https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app

Comment: Happy to help. For the `NaN`, you don't want to `++` the function [functions arent numbers :-) ] that's why you're getting NaN. You probably want to track a number, which you'll either have to pass into the function or use a global within the function. `getValue( counter++ )` or `var counter = 0;function getValue() {return nb++;}` @StackMagma